# How to push metrics to prometheus using client_golang?

Tags: go, prometheus

I have not yet able to find some good examples in using Gauge, Counter and Histogram in prometheus. Any help on this will do. I tried using the the documentation but I was not able to successfully create a working app.

Comment: Your question is unclear, as prometheus is a pull-based monitoring system.

Comment: I found the documentation for the python client much easier than the golang one.

Comment: Take a look at  https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics . It has clearer API and docs than `client_golang`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Prometheus is a pull-based system, if you want push-based monitoring, you need to use a gateway of some sort. A minimal example (without actually doing anything useful like starting an HTTP listener, or actually doing anything to a metric) follows:

```
import (
        "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
        "net/http"
)

var responseMetric = prometheus.NewHistogram(
        prometheus.HistogramOpts{
                Name: "request_duration_milliseconds",
                Help: "Request latency distribution",
                Buckets: prometheus.ExponentialBuckets(10.0, 1.13, 40),
        })

func main() {
        prometheus.MustRegister(responseMetric)
        http.Handle("/metrics", prometheus.Handler())
        // Any other setup, then an http.ListenAndServe here
}
```

You then need to configure Prometheus to scrape the `/metrics` page your binary provides.

Comment: @Efox Yes, I copied the wrong line, where it said "requestCounter", it should (as it now does) say "responseMetric".

Comment: Does it measures something already? How to add sample metrics on it?

Comment: I found the github page that has this source code in full [github](https://github.com/the-hobbes/mockingProduction/blob/f0019173f00ad6c631f21269bc7409001bc5e536/http_server/http.go)

Answer (score 19):

You could find examples form the [prometheus/client_golang](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/master/prometheus/push/examples_test.go). To get you started, you can just get the packages:

```
$ go get github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus
$ go get github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/push
```

The you can just run the following example by setting your correct pushgateway address, which is http://localhost:9091/ in this example:

```
package main
import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
        "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/push"
)

func ExamplePusher_Push() {
        completionTime := prometheus.NewGauge(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
                Name: "db_backup_last_completion_timestamp_seconds",
                Help: "The timestamp of the last successful completion of a DB backup.",
        })
        completionTime.SetToCurrentTime()
        if err := push.New("http://localhost:9091/", "db_backup").
                Collector(completionTime).
                Grouping("db", "customers").
                Push(); err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Could not push completion time to Pushgateway:", err)
        }
}
func main() {
        ExamplePusher_Push()
}
```

Run your script:

```
$ go run pushExample.go
```

After running your code, you should see the metrics at your gateway (http://localhost:9091/). The interface looks like the following:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have found this

`

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
)

var (
cpuTemp = prometheus.NewGauge(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
    Name: "cpu_temperature_celsius",
    Help: "Current temperature of the CPU.",
 })
hdFailures = prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts{
    Name: "hd_errors_total",
    Help: "Number of hard-disk errors.",
})
)

func init() {
    prometheus.MustRegister(cpuTemp)
    prometheus.MustRegister(hdFailures)
}

func main() {
    cpuTemp.Set(65.3)
    hdFailures.Inc()

    http.Handle("/metrics", prometheus.Handler())
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

`

This might be useful to some.